# jquery .data variable passing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass variables from a page to a jquery dialog and it is coming up as undefined in the resulting dialog.

I am passing the variable as so

```
 function attachModalEventHandler(){
    $("#tempModalLauncher").click(function(e){
        generateEditorModal(e, "#editorModal");
    });
 };

function generateEditorModal(e, identifier) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    tips.text("").removeClass();
    allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    $( identifier ).data('activeTemplate', selectedTemplate).dialog( "open" );
};
```

and then I am trying to read it from the modal

```
$("#reloadActiveDoc").click(function(e){
    var activeTemplate = $(this).data('activeTemplate');
    alert("You are editing: " + activeTemplate);
});
```

and while the variable works on the origin page, the resulting dialog page shows the variable as undefined.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I have an alert in the code that shows the variable, selectedTemplate, is filled. It comes from my datatable

```
 "fnRowSelected": function (nodes) {
    selectedTemplate = nodes[0].cells[1].innerHTML;
    alert( 'The row with ID '+ selectedTemplate + ' was selected' );
 };
```

and selectedTemplate is a global variable on the page

Comment: Where does that "selectedTemplate" variable come from? Have you logged its value at the time that code happens in "generateEditorModal"?

Comment: Where does the value `selectedTemplate` comes from..?